# How do I curve a brick mesh into a hexagonal shape?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm trying to model a brick tower that looks like this:

[image]

However, the tower has a hexagonal shape. With the curve/deform modifier, I can create a circular shape, but not the intended hexagonal shape. How do I go about modelling this?

Comment: I think the profiles of the towers are octagons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use the curve modifier, you just need a hexagonal curve.

Enable the 'Extra Objects' for curves addon by going to File> User Preferences> Addons> Add Curve> Extra Objects and ticking the checkbox.

The 'Add' menu now has extra objects, choose 'Curves Galore!'

[image]

Choosing 'Nsided' from the tool panel (<kbd>T</kbd>) and setting 'Sides' 6 will produce a hexagonal curve

[image]

You can then add several array modifiers on the brick before the curve modifier to create the rows of bricks.

I have also placed a 'Subsurf' modifier set to 'Simple' subdivision as the first modifier so that the bricks have a little more resolution to curve around the corners.

[image]